# How to move text if its too long?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website displays username at right top corner and if username is too big, it goes out of screen. How can I prevent this with using `html`, `css` and `JavaScript`.

I tried to use `text-align` and `direction` but it didn't work.

```
<div  style="font-size:15px; color:#666666; direction:RTL; text-align: right;" ><?php echo $_SESSION['Name']?></div
```

Comment: You *won't* need JavaScript. Decrease font-size or make more room. Make a Fiddle if you're really stuck.

Comment: Why do you use `direction:RTL`?

Comment: There are zillions of ways to prevent it, partly depending on what you want to happen (truncation, font size change, wrapping...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried `word-wrap:break-word;`

```
<div  style="font-size:15px; word-wrap:break-word; color:#666666; direction:RTL; text-align: right;" ><?php echo $_SESSION['Name']?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What exacly do want to do?
For example you can cut off the text with css and create "..." look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) for more info:

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

(this not works in Firefox)

The overflow property simply cuts off.

```
 overflow:hidden;
```

When you set an title attribute for the div the user can see the full name on hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  style="word-wrap:break-all; text-align: justify; word-break:break-all; font-size:15px; color:#666666; direction:RTL; text-align: right;" ><?php echo $_SESSION['Name']?></div>
```

`word-wrap:break-word;`doesn't work if user types without space
**like:Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa**

in this case you need

```
word-wrap:break-all; text-align: justify; word-break:break-all;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you should use the css-propertie `overflow` ([explain](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)) because the `word-wrap` propertie was not supported in any of the major browsers ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp))